# Tensor contaction using einsum

Tags: python, numpy

I've been reading the code where the tensor contractions is performed in the following way:

```
Ecorr = np.einsum('xscd,AbxS,as,SA->abcd',R_xsab,T_abxs,get.s('as'),get.s('sa'))
```

I am trying to understand how numpy does this operation, so that I attempted to split it into some steps:

```
tmp1 = np.einsum('xscd,as->xacd',R_xsab,get.s('as'))
tmp2 = np.einsum('abxS,SA->abxA',T_abxs,get.s('sa'))
Ecorr_test = np.einsum('xacd,Abxa->Abcd',tmp1,tmp2)
```

Unfortunately, it leads to different results.

Could anyone help me to understand what is going on under the hood of above einsum and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A quick observation.  You appear to mix up `a` and `A` at two levels.

Comment: While you compute tmp2 the result ordering is 'abxA', but when you use it to compute Ecorr_test , the ordering is 'Abxa'. Maybe here is the problem

Comment: In the original, `x`, `s`, `A`, `S` are summed, contracted.  Each appears twice of the LHS, and not on the right.  The `tmp2` step should reduce to `bx`.  It isn't obvious that splitting this into step makes it any easier to understand.